# Set quotas for disk usage to a system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, disk-usage, quota

I have a remote server.
Every time, after a short while, I have a problem with free space, my disk usage (/dev/sda) becomes 100%.

This is real problem because I can't easily free space. Most options (`sudo apt autoclean`, `pip uninstall ...`, `sudo apt autoremove`, etc) don't work because no free space left. Paradox :)

This is apparently a system problem (logs (and other) files takes a little bit more space than the system has for free usage)

How I can prevent taking 100% of "dev/sda" space and always rest some space to allow execute apt remove commands, pip uninstall commands and so on?
I know about `quota` package, but it's intended for user limiting, and my case is are system limiting.

Comment: Posting a partition table would help: `sudo cfdisk /dev/sda` and `df /dev/sda*`. If apt, logs etc are an issue, then the root partition is too small. sda itself is unlikely to be full, just non-optimally partitioned.

Comment: If you can't increase the filesystem size, forcibly limiting programs to write log files doesn't strike me as a good idea, I would not know how to do it anyway. Instead, put the logs and other storage (ab)users on a separate filesystem, or fix log rotation or whatever other configuration setting limits the amount of data that your services or applications generate.